# Nested Array of object, push dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, matrix

I Need to update a nested list of elements.

The list can have an infinite number of nested elements and I need to find them based on level and position to update the array.

Basically, I'm doing a tree view, and I need to add nodes dynamically, so it can be infinite nested nodes generated on the fly.

My basic structure is:

```js
const tree = {
  id: 'root',
  name: 'Project: ' + hxr.data.project.name,
  level: 0,
  children: [
    {
      id: 'deliverables',
      name: 'Deliverables',
      children: [
        {
          id: 'd1',
          name: 'Column A',
          children: [
            {
              id: 'c12',
              name: 'config',
              children: [],
              level: 1
            },
            {
              id: 'c123',
              name: 'orthomosaic',
              children: [],
              level: 1
            }
          ],
          level: 1
        },
        {
          id: 'd12',
          name: 'Column B',
          children: [
            {
              id: 'c121',
              name: 'config',
              children: [],
              level: 1
            }
          ],
          level: 1
        }
      ],
      level: 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Note this is an object, the first two levels will be always static, so, If I want to update the new elements, I’m doing:

```js
tree['children'][0]['children'].push(_node);
```

Where my node structure is:

```js
const _node = {
  id: uuid(),
  name: node.text,
  children: [],
  level: 1,
  type: node.type ?? 'folder'
}
```

My difficulty happens when I add dynamically a node and I want to add more elements to that node because I lose the reference.

In my mind it should be something like this:

```js
1
tree['children'][0]['children'][pos].push(_node);
2
tree['children'][0]['children'][pos]['children'].push(_node);
2
tree['children'][0]['children'][pos]['children'][pos2]['children'].push(_node);
```

But since it is dynamic, it could be infinite. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your question, given an arbitrary object path like `tree['children'][0]['children'][pos]['children'][pos2]['children']`, how to access that in the object?

Comment: No, how to generate that path dynamically based in the level given, for instance, if the level is 7 I need to repeat this 7 times to get to the expected level.

Comment: Not well defined question. So, convert for example array `[0, 3, 1]` to `tree['children'][0]['children'][3]['children'][1]['children'].push(_node)`?

Comment: How do you know what `pos` and `pos2` etc. are? Why not [`reduce`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) an array of indices? E.g. `[ 0, 1, 2, 1, 2 ].reduce((result, index) => result.children[index], tree).push(_node)`.

Comment: Sorry if the question is not well defined. 

@PeterThoeny no, the structure is prior given, and the function that I do to push the new object in the array gives me the level and the position but based on that level I need to create [level]['children'][position] as many times as the level needs. Does it make sense?

Comment: @SebastianSimon the first issue is that I need to keep the structure given first and expand based on that structure,  if I reduce the original array, how can I get back to the same object structure?

Comment: So how do you define/keep track of pos at any level?

Comment: @alexmorgan.cr You don’t reduce the original array. `tree` remains the same structure.

Comment: @PeterThoeny level is defined in a property of the object and the new object will take the parent level + 1, this is how I keep track of level.

Comment: @SebastianSimon can you show me an example?

Comment: @alexmorgan.cr I already showed you an example.

Comment: If you have *n* children at level 2, and you get a new object for level 3, what defines which object in level 2 gets the new child?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this in another way.

Since what I need was adding a child node to the selected, I add a id parameter and then perform a find deep function to the array to find and update the selected node.

```
function findDeep(array, id, node) {
        var object;
    
        array.some(function f(a) {
            if (a.id === id) {
                object = a;
                a.children.push(node)
                return true;
            }
            if (Array.isArray(a.children)) {
                return a.children.some(f);
            }
        });
        return object;
    }
```